# How to choose the Eclipse interface language?

Tags: eclipse, localization

I installed the Flash Builder Burrito edition and added it as a `dropin` to my Eclipse.

Now all the Eclipse interface is in French. I sincerely love my country but **Déboguer** and **Chemin de génération** are really not as sexy as **Debug** and **Build Path**.

I looked at my `eclipse.ini` file but there is not trace of a "French" language setting. The same for the `FlashBuilder.ini` file of my new Flash Builder.

Do you have any idea about how to get back the full English interface ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add in your eclipse-instance eclipse/configuration/config.ini the following line:

```
osgi.nl=en
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tom answer, you can do it adding this option to your eclipse.ini as runtime option:

```
   -ln
   en
```

Normally this file is more suitable to be customized.

Comment: your answer is not working. I got an error: could not initialize VM

Comment: I actually use this setting, so it works. You probably misplace putting it under --launcher.appendVmargs, so it is passed to the VM as argument instead of runtime option (as I wrote). Please do not vote if you are not sure.

Comment: Now I cannot remove the -1, until you edit your post.

Comment: Also downvoted because I tried adding those 2 lines to my eclipse.ini and it did nothing. This answer is too short and not helpful enough as it is. Answers should be easy to follow and understand and should not assume too much.